# How to implement Superscript & Subscript in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Does Blackberry support subscript superscript? I found the BlackBerry Forum thread ["Subscript and superscript in RichTextField"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Subscript-and-superscript-in-RichTextField/td-p/19990), but I am not able to access the BlackBerry knowledge base article.
How can I implement superscript & subscript in a LabelField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a problem accessing the BlackBerry knowledge base (i.e. from some countries?), here is the content of that page (posted by @MSohm of RIM):

> A RichTextField does not nativly support subscript, superscript or
>   multiple colours.  Multiple fonts, font sizes, and font formatting
>   (for example, Bold, Italic, Underlined) are supported.  The following
>   links explain this further.
>
> How To - Format text in a RichTextField Article Number: DB-00124 
>   http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Format-text-in-a-RichTextField/ta-p/445038
>
> How To - Change the text color of a field Article Number: DB-00114 
>   http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Change-the-text-color-of-a-field/ta-p/442951

---

If you still want to do this, you could try subclassing `RichTextField`, or `LabelField`, and overriding the `paint()` method.  There, you could change the font size and shift the y coordinate of the text.  It depends how generic you want to make the solution.  Perhaps you could post more information about your problem?

But, as a very simple, **hardcoded** example, the following code will create a `LabelField` that prints out: "**CO<sub>2</sub>**"

```
   private class SubscriptLabelField extends LabelField {

      private int _subscriptTop = 0;
      private int _subscriptFontSize = 0;

      public SubscriptLabelField(Object text, long style) {
         super(text, style);
         setFont(getFont());
      }

      public void setFont(Font newFont) {
         super.setFont(newFont);        

         // we use a subscript that's located at half the normal font's height,
         //   and is 2/3 as tall as the normal font
         int h = newFont.getHeight();
         _subscriptTop = h / 2;
         _subscriptFontSize = 2 * h / 3;
         super.invalidate();
      }

      protected void layout(int width, int height) {
         super.layout(width, height);

         // add more space at the bottom for the subscript
         int w = getExtent().width;
         int h = getExtent().height;
         int extraHeight = _subscriptFontSize - (getFont().getHeight() - _subscriptTop);
         setExtent(w, h + extraHeight);
      }

      public void paint(Graphics g) {
         // here we hardcode this method to simply draw the last char
         //  as a "subscript"
         String text = getText();
         String normalText = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
         g.drawText(normalText, 0, 0);

         // how much space will the normal text take up, horizontally?
         int advance = g.getFont().getAdvance(normalText);

         // make the subscript a smaller font
         Font oldFont = g.getFont();
         Font subscript = getFont().derive(Font.PLAIN, _subscriptFontSize);
         g.setFont(subscript);
         String subscriptText = text.substring(text.length() - 1);
         g.drawText(subscriptText, advance, _subscriptTop);

         // reset changes to graphics object just to be safe
         g.setFont(oldFont);
      }
   }
```

And then use it like this:

```
public SubscriptScreen() {
   super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);

   SubscriptLabelField textField = new SubscriptLabelField("C02", LabelField.NON_FOCUSABLE);

   // TODO: this line is just to show the adjusted boundaries of the field -> remove!
   textField.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.LIGHTGRAY));

   add(textField);
}
```

which gives:

[image]